# Filling Zillow Searchbox using VBA (Zillow is react-based website)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to identify the element for the search box, so that I can change the value of the search box to an address.  I was able to do this with redfin and pellago, but zillow is written with react, and I am having trouble.

I have already tried just about every element in "" I can see when I inspect element, but there is no real "name" or "id" like I am used to.

```
Sub WebscrapeZillow()

    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://zillow.com./"

    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Loop

    IE.document.getElementById("__next").Value = "hello world"

End Sub
```

I get a debug message every time.  I would like to enter an address in the search box.  I'm not sure I am "getting" the correct type of element or the correct item in "".  I have tried about 25 different element names, so "__next" is just the last I tried.  I have searched stackoverflow, and could not find what I thought was the answer (although I may not know exactly what I am looking for).  Thank you for any help!

Comment: This works for me: `IE.document.getElementsByClassName("Input-sc-7nzn9k-0")(0).Value = "hello world"`

Comment: Thank you!  I see where "Input-sc-7nzn9k-0" is, but for future reference, how would I know that is what I am looking for?  Additional question:  How do I give you points for helping me?

Comment: You're welcome! I added this as an answer and expanded on how I came up with the class name

Comment: You might want to check out the [Zillow API FAQ's](https://www.zillow.com/howto/api/faq.htm)

Answer (score 1):

To see which class or id to go after in your DOM you'll need to pull up zillow in a browser. In chrome and newer versions of IE, you can hit `F12` and it will bring up a developer panel where you can select elements on the page and see all of their attributes.

[image]

There are 3 classes for that search box that you can use `react-autosuggest__input`, `Input-sc-7nzn9k-0`, and `dIKGyt` so:

```
IE.document.getElementsByClassName("Input-sc-7nzn9k-0")(0).Value = "hello world"
```

I put that `(0)` after value because `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements that match that class. Here we just want "The first element that has this class", so `(0)` which works out here as there is only one element on that page that has that particular class.

Comment: Thank you!  Your answer is very helpful.  Gave you a thumbs up (doesn't register publicly for new people with 15 or less).  Thanks again!

Comment: My pleasure. No worries on the not registering. I'm just happy to help.